# How to assign a value to a position in a sequence in XQuery?

Tags: position, xquery, variable-assignment, sequence

I have a sequence of length $n initialized to zeroes:

```
let $seq := (for $i in (1 to $n) return 0)
```

I can access a position easily...

```
return $seq[5]
```

...but how do I update it? (the following doesn't work)

```
let $seq[5] := $seq[5] + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an XQuery implementation which supports XQuery 3 maps (eg. Saxon, BaseX), you could use these:

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";

(: Fill map with square numbers :)
let $map := map:new(
  for $i in (1 to 10)
  return map:entry($i, $i*$i)
)
(: Overwrite a single value :)
let $map := map:new(($map, map:entry(2, 5)))
(: Fetch this value :)
return map:get($map, 2)
```

But generally it is possible to solve a problem without maps and in most cases this code will probably run faster as it will get better optimized.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I just needed to think outside the box on this one.

Answer (score 0):

XQuery is a functional, not a procedural language, so variables are **immutable** - they cannot be updated once assigned. You would need to do something like this and create a new sequence:

```
let $seq2 := 
  for $n at $pos in $seq
  if ($pos eq 5) 
  then $n + 1
  else $n
```

Generally, in XQuery, it's best to design algorithms so that this type of mutable variable workaround isn't necessary. If you have data that needs to be updated, consider putting it in the database.

Comment: Note that there *are* extensions for some XQuery processors that allow updating variables, but it's generally not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but how do I update it? (the following doesn't work)
>
> ```
> let $seq[5] := $seq[5] + 1
> ```

**Using pure XPath** (which is also pure XQuery :)  **here is probably the shortest way to specify this:**

```
subsequence($seq, 1, 4), $seq[5] + 1, subsequence($seq, 6)
```

This produces a *new* sequence whose items are the same as the items of `$seq`, except that its 5th item's value is `$seq[5] + 1`.

As others have noted, XPath and XQuery are functional languages and among other things this means that a variable, once defined, cannot have its value modified.